# Are these implications regarding compactness correct?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the following true and if not how is it incorrect :

a subset of a metric space being compact $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ it is complete and totally bounded $\Rightarrow$ it is closed and totally bounded.

Comment: Everything is correct. Note that a metric space for itself is always closed.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you mean by "closed" when you talk about a "space".

Comment: First, on the left I presume you mean "a **metric** space being compact"; compactness is a property of more general topological spaces, and these implications do not make sense for a topological space which is not a metric space. Second, being "closed" is not a property of a metric space, it is instead a property of a subspace, so your second arrow does not make sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher ah okay so if I change space to subset of a metric space then everything is okay ?

Comment: Yes, everything will be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is essentially correct, but can be stated more precisely:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A \subset X$ be a metric subspace, so we give $A$ the metric $d_A$ induced from $d$ (just the restriction of $d$ to $A \times A$).

Then indeed $(A, d_A)$ is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded.
The compactness (or completeness plus total boundedness) does imply that $A$ is closed in $(X,d)$ (and also still totally bounded), but $A$ being closed in $(X,d)$ and totally bounded (under $d_A$) does not imply compactness of $(A,d_A)$. This *would* be true if $(X,d)$ were complete to start with, but not otherwise, e.g. take $X=(0,1)$ in the Euclidean metric and $A=X$, which is closed in $X$ (trivially) and totally bounded, but not compact.